Alien movie, which one was it?
I was trying to search for a movie I think I watched nearly 12 years back. Broken story was something like this. Some troopers going to find their companions and their plane crashes because some alien inside the plane. There was a young girl in that story. Last scene was a fight between an alien and the heroine where the heroine using some robot to fight the alien inside a rescue plane. Anyone knows the movie name?

Aspects of your description sound like James Cameron's Aliens
This movie revolves around a military team investigating a planetary colony that's broken off contact.  The troopers are accompanied by Ellen Ripley who is meant to act as a consultant, but has to get involved as they get stranded on the colony.  
The only survivor of the colony is a young girl.
A 'drop ship' does crash due to an alien.
The movie ends with Ripley in an exo-skeleton 'loader' fighting the mother alien.

This sounds like Aliens (the sequel to Alien directed by James Cameron) (1986): 



This features the exo-skeleton fight at the end
IMDB page: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090605/?ref_=nv_sr_1
Exo-skeleton fight scene: 
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090605/?ref_=nv_sr_1

Duh! obviously!
